# How to create route based security policy in Sails js?

Tags: authentication, sails.js

I've a Sails js app for 3 user groups, Site admin, Private User & Public user.

Now url pattern are like below for Admin,

```
'get /admin/foo': 'fooController.viewAll',
'post /admin/foo': 'fooController.add',
'put /admin/foo/:fooID': 'fooController.edit',
```

Url pattern for authenticated user,

```
'get /businesses/foo': 'fooController.viewAll',
'post /businesses/foo': 'fooController.add',
'put /businesses/foo/:fooID': 'fooController.edit',
```

Url pattern for public user,

```
'get /public/foo': 'fooController.viewAll',
```

I want to have a policy to authenticate user based on url pattern, if url is like /admin, it'll check user is admin? else if /business it will check whether user is our existing user or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field named `originalUrl` in request object. You can access it in your policy and decide depending on the url. Policy would be something like following.[I am assuming you know how to define a policy and add it in the configuration.]

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
        var originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        var tokenizedOriginalUrl = originalUrl.split('/');
        if(tokenizedOriginalUrl[0] == 'admin'){
            // do something
            next(null);
        }
        else if(tokenizedOriginalUrl[0] == 'business'){
            // do something
            next(null);
        }
        else if(tokenizedOriginalUrl[0] == 'public'){
            // do something
            next(null);
        }
        else{
            next("Access prohibited.");
        }
};
```